# Photocoupler to Latch Microcontroller Power Supply

Tags: arduino, power-supply, relay, circuit-design, latch

I'm revising my custom arduino circuit which involves powering an atmega328p. I am using a 9V battery connected to a BS170 MOSFET. Without any voltage applied to the gate of my BS170, the battery is disconnected from my regulator which powers my Arduino. Applying over 5 volts to the gate connects the battery and my arduino turns on. This part works flawlessly but my issue is that this gate voltage will only be applied for 5 seconds and I need to keep the arduino on for about 20s. My question is, using an optocoupler such as this [one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/TLP222AF/TLP222AF-ND/871243), could I use an arduino output pin connected as shown below and set it high to latch the power on until a timer counts to ~20s. At this point I would set the pin low and the photocoupler would become open. It seems like it could work but would I have any problems with the optocoupler and MOSFET in that configuration? Does this seem like its okay?

[image]

Comment: The opto wont conduct enough current and the MOSFET Vgs may not be enough.  Get an LDO with an enable input like LP2989AIMM-5.0 then use logic OR input.

Comment: "Applying over 5 volts to the gate connects the battery and my arduino turns on." - it better be **a lot** over 5V, or the MOSFET won't be fully turned on. The way you have the opto-coupler wired it has to handle the full current going to the Arduino. Can you use it to hold up the voltage on the MOSFET's Gate instead?

Comment: So the Vin to the MOSFET is controlled by an external machine that is typically about 10 volts. I guess I'm not sure what you mean by using the optocoupler to hold the Gate high, I've never used an optocoupler before so I'm just a little lost. So you are saying though that using the arduino output at the opto pin 1 will use too much current? Or that it wouldn't be enough to turn the opto on, connecting pin 4 and 3, and connecting the battery?